# how to update clang compiler on MacOS to clang-16 (to get C++23 functionality)

Tags: c++, macos, clang, llvm

I'm using MacOS.  Homebrew already has clang:  Version 14.  But clang-14 doesn't support the recent C++20 and C++23 updates.
How do I update my compiler from clang 14 to clang 16?

I have tried  `brew update clang`

I have tried  `brew install llvm@16`

Even after reloading the terminal with `source ~/.zshrc`, `clang --version` still shows version 14.0.0.

```
% clang --version
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Do I need to uninstall clang-14 and *then* install clang-16?

Comment: Take a carefull look at the version `Apple clang version 14.0.0` and the path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`. This is not homebrew installed LLVM clang. Research the content of `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

Comment: I got Homebrew clang 16 installed and once I had added the following to ~/.zshrc it was available on the command line: `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"` So now it finds Homebrew clang version 16.0.6 instead of Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1).
Finally, to ensure CMake finds clang 16, I added the following to ~/.zshrc:  `export CC=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang 
export CXX=/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang++`